# Multiple path environment variable setup lines with bash

Tags: bash, environment-variables, path

I have very long `export PATH=A:B:C ...`. Can I make a multiple lines to have more organized one as follows?

```
export PATH = A:
              B:
              C:
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do:

```
export PATH="A"
export PATH="$PATH:B"
export PATH="$PATH:C"
```

Each subsequent line appends onto the previously defined path. This is generally a good habit, as it avoids trashing the existing path. If you want the new component to take precedence, swap the order:

```
export PATH="A"
export PATH="B:$PATH"
export PATH="C:$PATH"
```

Alternatively, you might be able to do:

```
export PATH=A:\
B:\ 
C
```

where `\` marks a line continuation. Haven't tested this method.

Comment: Note that `export` is a built-in command, not a keyword nor a syntactic assignment. So if you have `PATH` elements containing whitespace (or glob characters), you do need double quotes around `export PATH="$PATH:B"`. You could also write `PATH=$PATH:B` and so on; you only need to `export` a variable once, not every time it changes (except in some very old Bourne shells), and you don't need the double quotes in an assignment.

Comment: Also `PATH+=:B` works for string concatenation.

Answer (score 4):

You can extend lines in bash using a backslash at the end of a line like this:

```
export PATH=/path/A:\
/path/B:\
/path/C
```

Please note that the absence of white space is important here.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```bsh
export PATH=$(tr -d $'\n ' <<< "
   /path/A:
   /path/B:
   /path/C")
```

Has the added benefit of not messing up your indent levels.